# Delete function is not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, rest

I wrote below code in my app.js file (this is a rest api angularjs project)

```
.controller('HomeCtrl'['$scope','Questions','$route',function($scope,Questions,$route) {

    var id = $route.id;

    Questions.get(function(data) {            
        $scope.questions = data.response;
    });

    $scope.remove = function(id) {  

        window.alert("works");
        //var id = $scope.question[id];
        // document.write(id);

        Questions.delete({id:id}).$promise.then(function(data) { 
            if(data.response){                 
               $route.reload();                 
          }                
        } , function(){
               alert("2nd");
             }

         );
     };
}])
```

first alert box and second alert box is apearing. but

```
Questions.delete({id:id}).$promise.then(function(data) { 
    if (data.response) {                 
        $route.reload();                 
}
```

is not working. Questions.delete({id:id}) is "true". but why don't it go inside?.

Here are my other codes for delete function.

from template list.html

```
<a class="trash" ng-click="remove(question.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

rest model class

```
private function delete($id) {     

    $this->db->where('id',$id)->delete('questions');

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return NULL;    

}
```

rest controller class

```
public function index_delete($id)   {

    if (!$id) {
        $this->response(NULL,400);
    }

    $delete = $this->questions_model->delete($id);

    if(!is_null($delete)) {

          $this->response(array( "response" =>"deleted"),200);

    } else {

        $this->response(array("error" => "cud not save"),404);

    }   

    } 

}
```

can some one tell me what is missing here?. 
Thanks,

Comment: Does the question is actually being deleted from the DB? Don't you need to check `if(data.response.deleted){` (If not - write `console.log(data)` in the promise success callback to see what is actually returned from the server)

Comment: data.response.deleted didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a little mistake. When I changed private delete to public delete it worked finally.